# Shift date by months but keep the same day

Tags: c#, algorithm, date

I am trying to shift a date by a number of given months, but also to keep the same day (for example, if the day of the date is Monday, and after shifting with x months the day is Thursday, I want also to subtract 3 days from the new obtained date. This algorithm should add/subtract days depending on the new obtained date, basically providing the closest date that represents the same day of week). As an example, if I have the start date 10.08.2016(Wednesday), and I add 3 months, I will get 10.11.2016(Thursday), so the closest Wednesday to that day is 09.11.2016.

What I managed to make till now looks something like this:

```
int startDayOfWeek = ((int)startDay.DayOfWeek) == 0 ? 7 : (int)startDay.DayOfWeek;
int newStartDayOfWeek = ((int)startDay.AddMonths(period).DayOfWeek) == 0 ? 7 : (int)startDay.AddMonths(period).DayOfWeek;
int shiftingDays = startDayOfWeek - newStartDayOfWeek;

if (shiftingDays > 3)
    shiftingDays -= 7;
```

where startDay is the start date, and period is the number of months I want to shift to.

But this still fails some times, so any tips would be greately appreciated.

An example when this code fails would be:
startDate = 01.08.2016 (Monday) and period would be 5
After adding 5 months, I get 01.01.2017, which is Sunday, and the closest Monday would be on 02.01.2017, but I get -6 days.

Comment: What are the circumstances where it fails?

Comment: Use : new DateTime(startDayOfWeek.Year, startDayOfWeek.month + 1,startDayOfWeek.day).

Comment: What should it do when you shift, for example, 31 January by one month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code. The idea is to divide the days by 7, round it, and multiply by 7.

```
DateTime endDate = startDay.AddMonths((int)period);
endDate = startDay.AddDays((int)Math.Round((double)(endDate - startDay ).Days / 7)*7);
```

Comment: rounding is done while dividing integer: `int result = 5 / 2; // 2` and `int result = 3 / 2; // 1`

Comment: No, division truncate decimal part, not rounded

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for ?

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    //DateTime startDay = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime startDay = new DateTime( 2016, 8, 1 );
    //DateTime startDay = new DateTime( 2016, 8, 10 );

    DateTime newDay = startDay.AddMonths( 5 );

    int startDayOfWeek = (int)startDay.DayOfWeek;
    int newDayOfWeek = (int)newDay.DayOfWeek;

    int shift1 = (7 + startDayOfWeek - newDayOfWeek) % 7;
    int shift2 = (7 + newDayOfWeek - startDayOfWeek) % 7;

    DateTime test = newDay + ((shift1 > shift2) ? - TimeSpan.FromDays( shift2 ) : TimeSpan.FromDays( shift1 ));
}
```